# Web browser connection in codename one

Tags: codenameone

when url like youtube.com or others are set, it opens in webBrowser but when pdf link is kept nothing happens, why is that??

```
     WebBrowser pdfview = new WebBrowser();
                pdfview.setURL("http://www.codenameone.com/files/developer-guide.pdf");  
//this link downloads the pdf file in browser but does nothing in codename one browser...
                f.addComponent(pdfview);
```

i jst want to view this pdf from the browser

Comment: Did you try that on device or Simulator?

Comment: i checked in android devices also but doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Opening a PDF in the browser component will only work on devices and won't work in the simulator.

Comment: i had tried in android mobiles too, it opens a blank form and doesnt work. however i went through google group and found out that if i set the https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/79655/gazelle.pdf  as my url it works... and so is my case as well

Comment: Moreover i used Util.downloadToFile too so that the pdf can be downloaded. It works fine. But i want to make sure if there is a pdf reader in the device. If there is, then it opens in pdf reader automatically (Display.getInstance().execute(filename). If there isn't i want to show pdf in web browser. To achieve this, i need to a way to know if there is pdf reader in the mobile device. How can i search if there is pdf reader installed or not??

Comment: That's a problem on Android as far as I can tell. File an issue on this in github, I think we should have a more common way to view external files than Display.execute and PDF is a common use case.

Comment: i have a question related to pdf again, i managed to download and view the pdf in devices but if the device doesnt have any application that can read pdf file, then what can be done? Can we know in advance there is no software to read pdf and display download pdf reader first?

Comment: No. There is canExecute but it's for iOS and has no Android equivalent to my knowledge.

Comment: hello shai i had filed an issue of not opening pdf file last time, it is told that the problem is solved but still it is not working. Ps i have already updated to 3.3.4 and updated the library of the project, clean & build as well. Please have a look: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1616

Comment: It works with a "file:" URL. HTTP URL's should open in the browser.

Comment: In the Display.execute not in the web browser. We have limited control over the inner workings of the native web browser.

Comment: i downloaded the file and use display.execute it works fine but if the user want to view the pdf first before downloading can't we show it in web-browser component? Or if there is no pdf viewer in the user device, it'll be good to show it in web-broswer component, isn't it?

Comment: You can just use Display.execute with an http URL